# Warning refers to unrecognized command, but file can still be compiled

Tags: packages, compiling, texstudio

Good afternoon everyone,

I am using a master document in TeXstudio which imports several separate .tex-files and contains the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{packBWR}
\begin{document}

\input{TeX-files/Sep_file1.tex}
\clearpage

\input{TeX-files/Sep_file2.tex}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

In these subdocuments (that are called by the input command), the compiler indicates that it cannot recognise commands, such as align and bmatrix. When I compile the whole document through for instance Sep_file1.tex, the whole document is updated without any warnings and errors remaining.

I suspect that the packages cannot be detected in the subdocuments before the compilation process starts. How can I solve these warnings, so I can prevent that most of the code turns into a red block?

Extra information:
The file *packBWR.sty* is a custom package file, which includes the following packages and alterations:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry} % side margins of 1cm
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % section numbering also in eqns.
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % no indentations
```

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you mean with errors in the subdocuments. Do you try to compile them with LaTeX on their own or do you mean unrecognized commands in the TeX editor or what ever you are using for editing?

Comment: I edited my question in order to clarify what I mean with subdocuments: the 'included' .tex-files from the \input command.

Comment: Are you trying to compile every seperated file of its own?

Comment: your description that "most of the code turns into a red block" indicates that the lack of recognition is in the editor.  what editor are you using?  (i am sure i can't help there, but with knowledge of what that tool is, someone else probably can.)  `align` and `bmatrix` are defined in `amsmath`, so since that is read in via `packBWR.sty` during the latex run, there is no problem during the actual compilation.

Comment: Johannes, I am compiling my full document through one of the included files; I do not want to compile the separate documents. As I defined a session with the given main file including Sep_file1.tex and Sep_file2.tex, I am able to compile the full document within any included document. Barbara, I am using TeXstudio.

Comment: You can make your main tex file the *master file* and compile the document in its whole even when *inside* one of the included files. Place the checkmark somewhere within *Options* while having the master file open.

Comment: I am able already to compile the document from either the main file or one of the included ones. The main problem is that the included files do not recognise the non-standard commands of LaTeX as the main document does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeXstudio tries, to determine the valid commands in a document. For details see [FAQ: How does TeXstudio know about valid commands?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands)

However, this detection is not perfect. It may be inaccurate depending on the content of your style file. Note, also that local style files are currently not interperted by TXS (i.e. putting the sty file next to the tex document). The solution is to create a [custom cwl file](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: At this point, it seems more easy to reinclude the packages in the main document, instead of creating a custom cwl file that has to be made and placed with the installion folders of TeXstudio.. But, thanks for the explanation!